# Take full args list after command (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello wonderful internet people

I am writing code to set the status of my bot in discord.js. I am wondering how I can take a user's full args list and put it into one let statement, like saying (args[0] + ' ' + args[1], etc)

Here is my current code

Thank you, hope you have a great day

```
let statgame = (args[0])
    client.user.setActivity(statgame);
```

Answer (score 3):

Given args is an array, JS provides a join function that does this for you

```
let joinedArgs = args.join(" ");
```

The first argument is the string that separates each element

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you 100%. From what I understood you can achieve this with arguments object [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```
function myargs() { console.log([...arguments].join(' ')) }
```