# Long discord.js arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm starting with discord.js and I have a question. Is it possible to make an infinite argument currently I have to use `message.channel.send(${args})` and for example when I type $test 1 2 only 1 will be sent and 2 will not please help I wanted to make a reason for the command $kick but only one argument the first is often seen only the first sentence instead of the whole reason please help!

I don't think you know what I mean, I mean that the argument should not be a single word, for example command:$embed hello word :) I want the bot to send: hello word :) but it sends: hello without word and :) it doesn't have to be hello word :) it has to be the words given by the user I hope I wrote it clearly for any help thank you!

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const prefix = "$";
const RED  = "#EC0F0F";
const BLUE = "#1725E7";
const GREEN = "#17E729";
const FIOLET = "#880FEC";


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');

});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    console.log(message.content);

    if (message.content === `$embed`) {
      const embesmess = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${args[0]}`)
      .setColor(`${GREEN}`)
      .setdescription(`HERE I WANT THIS ARGUMENT`)

      message.channel.send(embesmess);
    }

}); 

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take full args list after command (Discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179874/take-full-args-list-after-command-discord-js)

Comment: So you want all but `args[0]` joined by a space?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes and no limit so I can give many sentences and the bot will send them

Comment: So take all but `args[0]` and join them with a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`$embed`)) {
      const embesmess = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${args.slice(1).join(" ")}`) //join all arguments besides the first
      .setColor(`${GREEN}`)
      .setdescription(`HERE I WANT THIS ARGUMENT`)

      message.channel.send(embesmess);
    }
```

This will combine all of your arguments excluding the first.